# Run Rails Server and Grunt Watch on Vagrant Boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruntjs, vagrant

I want to have my Rails app running on 'vagrant up' without needing to ssh the VM and manually run 'rails server'.

In order to do that, I have in my default.rb recipe:

```
execute "rails server" do
  command "cd /vagrant && rails server"
end
```

which keeps my terminal running and actually gives me a rails server running.

**The issue comes when** I want to additionally have running a 'grunt watch' also on 'vagrant up'.

```
execute "grunt watch" do
  command "cd /vagrant && grunt watch"
end
```

The problem is that, as **'rails server' runs before and it doesn't run in background**, 'grunt watch' never gets executed.

Therefore, I appended '&' to both commands in order to run them in background, but after running 'vagrant up' successfully, none the rails server o the grunt watch are running.

I also tried preappending 'nohup' command, but I didn't work neither.

Any guide here?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is:

```
execute "rails server and grunt watch" do
    command "cd /vagrant && rails server & cd /vagrant && grunt watch"
end
```